# Nifi Attributes to JSON alters my json data order

Tags: json, attributes, streaming, iot, apache-nifi

**BACKGROUND:**

I want to alter my JSON slightly from

```
{
  "d0" : 0.0,
  "d1" : 0.0,
  "d2" : 0.0,
  "d3" : 0.0,
  "d4" : 0.0,
  "d5" : 0.0,
  "d6" : 0.0,
  "d7" : 0.0
}
```

to

```
{ "d0" : [0.0],
  "d1" : [0.0],
  "d2" : [0.0],
  "d3" : [0.0]
  "d4" : [0.0],
  "d5" : [0.0],
  "d6" : [0.0],
  "d7" : [0.0]

}
```

and I am following the reply to the question given here https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Groovy-Script-in-ExecuteScript-Processor-To-Format-Date/td-p/230207

**Accordingly, I use-**

1.EvaluateJsonPath
2.UpdateAttribute 
3.AttributesToJson

and that part of my Nifi processing looks like this

[related nifi flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp7Vu.png)

**My settings for the 3 processors are -**

**1.EvaluateJsonPath**

[settings/ configuration for EvaluateJsonPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SbmN.png)

**2.UpdateAttribute**

[settings/ configuration for UpdateAttribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8i6H.png)

**3.AttributesToJson**

[settings/ configuration for AttributesToJson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WG0w.png)

But the AttributesToJson just changes the order of the data in the flat JSON to be

```
{
  "d4" : [0.0],
  "d5" : [0.0],
  "d6" : [0.0],
  "d7" : [0.0],
  "d0" : [0.0],
  "d1" : [0.0],
  "d2" : [0.0],
  "d3" : [0.0]
}
```

**QUESTION:**

Why is the  AttributesToJson behaving this way? How should I change it to the correct order starting d0 to d7?
I need the correct order because this is supposed to be the body of a POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`JoltTransformJson`](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/NiFi-How-to-use-JOLT-to-add-json-key-value-dynamically-to/td-p/222329) processor to get the json columns in the desired order and keep the following

**`spec:`**

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "d1": "d1",
      "d2": "d2",
      "d3": "d3",
      "d4": "d4",
      "d5": "d5",
      "d6": "d6",
      "d7": "d7"
    }
  }
]
```

Now output flowfile will be in the correct order you are expecting:

```
{
  "d1" : [ 0 ],
  "d2" : [ 0 ],
  "d3" : [ 0 ],
  "d4" : [ 0 ],
  "d5" : [ 0 ],
  "d6" : [ 0 ],
  "d7" : [ 0 ]
}
```

(Or)

Another way would be using **`Query Record processor`** configure Record Reader/writer and add new sql query with your column names in the correct order.

Comment: thanks. JoltTransformJson solves the problem. But I realize I have another issue which I need to solve before. I have explained it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58526588/nifi-processor-or-ways-to-alter-my-json-structure